# download file from a folder using php

Tags: php, html

I need to download csv file from `export` folder which is inside the `www` folder.
I could make it as link, but by attempting to save as the csv files, an empty csv file will be downloaded. Any idea?

```
<?php
$dir_open = opendir('./export');

while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
    $link = "<a href='./$filename'> $filename </a><br />";

    echo $link;
}
}
closedir($dir_open);
?>
```

the result links are like:
[image]

by right clicking and selecting save link as, an empty csv file is downloaded

Comment: In the `href` part you'll need to add the `export` folder. Not just the filename.

Comment: you are linking to ./$filename, whereas the files are stored under ./export/$filename

Comment: thanks Daan, it works

Answer (score 1):

Try this one which i used this. Ex: download.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['link']))
{
    $var_1 = $_GET['link'];

    $dir = "export/"; 
    $file = $dir . $var_1;

    if (file_exists($file))
    {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
       ob_clean();
       flush();
       readfile($file);
       exit;
    }
} 
?>
```

I used a link like this

```
$link = "<a href='download.php?link=$filename'> $filename </a><br />";
```